# SQL Server Database Autogrowth 1mb to 1gb and Defragmentation

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Say there was a database with 1mb autogrowth and it was changed to 500mb (on SQL Server 2008 and up).

What is the best way the fragmentation caused by the original setting of 1mb autogrowth be solved?

Is de-fragmentation required on the OS level? Or will rebuilding the indexes be all that is required to revive the performance and speed of the db? (assuming that indexes are correct and optimal to begin with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For data files: Small file growth causes OS-level fragmentation only. Defragment the files if necessary. This can cause high disk load.

For log files: Follow the usual procedures for analyzing and resolving VLF fragmentation.